# GROK (regular expressions), field with backslash, space and a long

Tags: regex, logstash

I'm using Logstash to get some text out of a string and create a field.
The string of the message is:

```
"\"07/12/2016 16:21:24.652\",\"13.99\",\"1467351040\""
```

I can't figure it out how to get three results, being the first:

```
07/12/2016 16:21:24.652
```

The second

```
13.99
```

The third

```
1467351040
```

Comment: Try `"(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)","(?<price>\d+(\.\d+)?)","(?<id>\d+)"`

Comment: Forward slashes aren't allowed.

Comment: So, escape them if they are not allowed. `"(?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)","(?<price>\d+(\.\d+)?)","‌​(?<id>\d+)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The point of grok pattern is to avoid having to write the regex and use predefined patterns

Comment: @baudsp Unless you need something more specific. I know what patterns Grok has, I just suggested a specific expression for a cleaner output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True. But in that case, they were not needed (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match => {
   "message"=> [
       "\\"%{DATESTAMP:a}\\",\\"%{NUMBER:b}\\",\\"%{NUMBER:c}\\""
   ]
}
```

To help the next time you have to craft a grok pattern:

1. [GrokConstructor, to test your pattern](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result)
2. [The main patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)
3. [Grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

Comment: That's exactly where I'm comming from.
I tried pattern; "([^"]*)")
But the config of Logstash is failing.

I also don't know how to filter between quotes, between a '/'

Comment: @Kevin More important, does my answer help you?

Comment: Yes it does, a lot. It at least pointed me in the right direction, instead of trying to doing RegEx myself.

But still no luck with 

     grok
  { match => ["message", "%{DATESTAMP:a} %{NUMBER:b} %{NUMBER:c}"]
  }

Comment: @Kevin I tried this configuration : `input {
    stdin {}
}


filter { 
grok{
match => {
"message"=> [
"\\"%{DATESTAMP:a}\\",\\"%{NUMBER:b}\\",\\"%{NUMBER:c}\\""
]}
}
} 

    output { stdout { codec => "rubydebug" } }` with this input: `\"07/12/2016 16:21:24.652\",\"13.99\",\"1467351040\"` and I got this result: ...

Comment: ...`  {
       "message" => "\\\"07/12/2016 16:21:24.652\\\",\\\"13.99\\\",\\\"1467351040\\\"\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-12T15:14:20.933Z",
          "host" => "FREIFDKT0021127",
             "a" => "07/12/2016 16:21:24.652",
             "b" => "13.99",
             "c" => "1467351040"
}`

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct line indeed.
I had to remove one backslash for my own config. Thanks very much. Saves me a lot of time and stuff.

```
grok{ match => { "message"=> [ "\"%{DATESTAMP:a}\",\"%{NUMBER:b}\",\"%{NUMBER:c}\"" ]} }
```